# does passportjs automatically add user to res.locals?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

In my template, settings.pug, user.name is being accessed. Which is unclear how it's getting there as controller looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('settings');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind I found code that I had written long time ago in main controller

```
router.use(function(req,res,next){
  if (req.user) res.locals.user = req.user;
  next();
});
```